# Constant regisitration fail

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm currently trying to create a registration form for my website (this has worked in the past)

and I keep getting a registration fail, no errors are appearing - has anyone got any ideas why?

I used to have a recaptcha function within it but I don't see that being the issue.

I've tried to fix this for days.

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
if (!empty($username = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'username', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)) AND !empty($email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL)) AND !empty($password = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)) AND !empty($password2 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password2', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING))) {
$password = EncryptPasswords($password);
$password2 = EncryptPasswords($password2);

$qry = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`=:username");
$qry->execute(["username"=>$username]);

if ($qry->rowCount() == 0) {

$qry = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `email`=:email");
$qry->execute(["email"=>$email]);

if ($qry->rowCount() == 0) {

if ($password == $password2) {

$random = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 86)), 0, 86);
$RANDOMqry = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `access_token`=:id");
$RANDOMqry->execute(["id"=>$random]);

while ($RANDOMqry->rowCount() > 0) {
$random = substr(str_shuffle(str_repeat("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 86)), 0, 86);
$RANDOMqry = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `access_token`=:id");
$RANDOMqry->execute(["id"=>$random]);
}

$REGqry = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`username`, `email`, `email_ver`, `password`, `access_token`, `registered`, `rank`)
VALUES
(:user, :email, :veri, :password, :access, :times, :ranks)");

$REGexct = $REGqry->execute(["user"=>$username, "email"=>$email, "veri"=>"no", "password"=>$password, "access"=>$random, "times"=>$timestamp, "ranks"=>"2"]);

if ($REGexct) {

$qry = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username`=:username");
$qry->execute(["username"=>$username]);
$row = $qry->fetch();

setcookie('accesstoken',$row->access_token,time()+(86400 * 14),'/');
setcookie('_uc_id',$row->id,time()+(86400 * 14),'/');
setcookie('_uc_pw',$row->password,time()+(86400 * 14),'/');

$_SESSION['cerror'] = '<div class="alert alert-success">Your account has been registered, please enter the following information correctly or leave it for a further date.</div>';
header('Location: /members/register-details');
exit();


} else {
$_SESSION['cerror'] = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Error: </strong>Registration Failed.</div>';
header('Location: '.$cwd);
exit();
}



          } else {
            $_SESSION['cerror'] = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Error: </strong>Passwords do not match.</div>';
            header('Location: '.$cwd);
            exit();
          }

      } else {
        $_SESSION['cerror'] = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Error: </strong>That email is already in use, you\'ll need to pick another.</div>';
        header('Location: '.$cwd);
        exit();
      }

    } else {
      $_SESSION['cerror'] = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Error: </strong>That username already exists, you\'ll need to pick another.</div>';
      header('Location: '.$cwd);
      exit();
    }
  } else {
    $_SESSION['cerror'] = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Error: </strong>You must fill in all of the details to log in.</div>';
    header('Location: '.$cwd);
    exit();
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form action method="post">
<div class="form-group">
<input name="username" type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Choose a username" autocomplete="off" autofocus />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input name="email" type="email" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Enter your email address" autocomplete="off" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input name="password" type="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Choose a password" autocomplete="off" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<input name="password2" type="password" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Confirm your password" autocomplete="off" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdJYZAUAAAAALere0Qs9ns7S4nMUajPKsHWXGOr"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<button name="register" type="submit" class="button button-login pull-right"><i class="fas fa-plus-square"></i> Register</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text** or a weak hash like **SHA1 or MD5**.

Comment: What is `EncryptPasswords`? This doesn't look very secure since it produces output that can be compared with other output, making dictionary attacks on your passwords trivial. Use [`password_hash`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) instead. Do not write your own encryption or hashing code.

Comment: Could you show us how you open the PDO connection?

Comment: PDO is connected via this: `include_once(realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]) .'/backend/imp/config.php'); // Connecting the configuration file.`

Comment: That doesn't show how it connects, that shows *where* it connects.

Comment: $dsn = "mysql:host=...;dbname=...";
$con = new PDO($dsn, '.user.', 'password');
$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

Comment: However, the database works - I collect information from it.